# Why does SunOS say it can't execute this KornShell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, solaris, ksh

I have a KornShell (ksh) script in Server A that will run a script in ServerB.

```
    #!/bin/ksh/
    ssh user@server "/path/script.sh"
```

The script permissions are as follow:

```
 -rwxrwxrwx   1 user    dba           75 Jun 11 10:00 script.sh
```

I checked the existence of 'ksh' in /bin and its there. (bash is not)

When I try to run the script I get 
     `./script.sh: cannot execute`

What could be happening? I tested the ssh command manually and it works.

Its a SunOS system.

Comment: Try removing the slash after ksh

Comment: It's not a Bash script if it has "ksh" in the shebang. Also, don't *ever* set permissions to 777. At the very least change it to 775.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation... as you can tell Im starting with all this stuff now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the trailing `/` in  `#!/bin/ksh/`.. leaving it there causes an error for me too.

This is the message I get with the trailing slash under Linux (more descriptive than SunOS it appears):

```
ksh: ./so2.sh: cannot execute [Not a directory]
```